# If a set of vectors is a basis and S is a span for some positive integer k<n, then S transpose = span (Vk+1...Vn)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, span, transpose

So if `V1,....Vn` is a basis for R^n and S = span`V1,...Vk` for some positive interger kVk+1,....Vn.

I am pretty sure that this statement is true... because S transpose cannot be greater than S or else it'll be in R^(n+1)... I am not really sure how to prove it though... I could be wrong as well :( Please help!

Actual Question: https://gyazo.com/0bdca978f9440383bd13e1a260199fda

Answer (score 0):

The formulation you stated doesn't make sense, fortunately I could
read your link. 
The statement is definetely true that
\begin{equation}
S^{\bot}=span(v_{k+1},..,v_{n})
\end{equation}
Let say $w$ is orthogonal to $S$ which means $w\in S^{\bot}$ or in other form
\begin{equation}
(w,h)=0,\quad\forall h\in S
\end{equation}
Then since $v_{1},..v_{n}$ is a base then $w=\sum\xi^{i}v_{i}$ e
\begin{equation}
(w,h)=(\sum\xi^{i}v_{i},h)=\sum\xi^{i}(v_{i},h)=0
\end{equation}
choosing $h=v_{1}$ this imply that $\xi^{1}=0$. Proceeding the same way if we choose $h=v_{i}$ with $i=1...k$ then we have that $\xi^{i}=0$ for $i=1...k$ which
means that 
\begin{equation}
w\in span(v_{k+1},..,v_{n})
\end{equation}
To be really strict we only demonstrate that the orthogonal space include the $span(v_{k+1},..,v_{n})$, the converse is given directly confirming that $v_{k+1},..,v_{n}\in S^{\bot}$